# Conflict between thmtools and hyperref/autoref

Tags: hyperref, thmtools, autoref

I want to use `\autoref` in an entry in the PDF toc (the purpose is a appendix with proofs). But unfortunately the three ingredients `\addcontentsline`, `\autoref`, `thmtools` conflict with a cryptic error message.

Minimal (not) working example:

```latex
\documentclass[final]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheorem{definition}

\begin{document}
\section{Main document}
\label{mysec}
\begin{definition} \label{mydef}
    The definition.
\end{definition}

\section{Additional Details}
In the following line, autoref works:
\subsection*{About \autoref{mydef}}
% the following lines work:
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Details for~\autoref{mysec}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Details for~\ref{mydef}}%
% but this here breaks:
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Details for~\autoref{mydef}}%
What causes autoref to break?
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
./thmtools-vs-autoref.tex:27: Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition.
\@uclclist ->\oe 
                 \OE \o \O \ae \AE \dh \DH \dj \DJ \l \L \ng \NG \ss \SS \th...
l.27 ...}{subsection}{Details for~\autoref{mydef}}
                                                  %
?
```

and I'm on texlive 2021 (arch linux `texlive-core 2021.58710-2)

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thmtools defines `\definitionautorefname` as

```
 \protect \MakeUppercase  {d}efinition
```

And this definition is not safe there.

You could redefine it:

```
\documentclass[final]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheorem{definition}

\renewcommand\definitionautorefname{Definition}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Main document}
\label{mysec}
\begin{definition} \label{mydef}
    The definition.
\end{definition}

\section{Additional Details}
In the following line, autoref works:
\subsection*{About \autoref{mydef}}
% the following lines work:
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Details for~\autoref{mysec}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Details for~\ref{mydef}}%
% but this here breaks:
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Details for~\autoref{mydef}}%
What causes autoref to break?
\end{document}
```

I removed inputenc. In a current latex utf8 is the default.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what does not safe *there* mean? By the way, one can also directly do `\declaretheorem[name=Definition]{definition}` (which looks a bit cleaner since it avoids the automated case conversion)